# A proof of Transfinite Induction

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, ordinals

This is my proof of Transfinite Induction by filling the gaps in my textbook. It would be great if someone help me verify if i correctly understand what is meant by the authors!

---

> Let $P(\alpha)$ is a property defined for all ordinals $\alpha$. Suppose that $P(\alpha)$ is true for all $\alpha<\beta$ implies $P(\beta)$ is also true. Then $P(\alpha)$ is true for all ordinals $\alpha$.

**My attempt:**

Assume the contrary that $P(\gamma)$ is not true for some ordinal $\gamma$.

Let $F:=\{\alpha \in\gamma\cup\{\gamma\}\mid P(\alpha) \text{ is not true}\}$.

It follows that $\gamma\in F$ and thus $F\neq\emptyset$, and that $F$ is a set of ordinals and thus is well-ordered.

Let $\beta=\min F$. Then $\alpha\notin F$ for all $\alpha<\beta$. This implies that $P(\alpha)$ is true for all $\alpha<\beta$. By inductive hypothesis, $P(\beta)$ is also true and thus $\beta\notin F$. This is a contradiction.

Hence $P(\alpha)$ is true for all ordinals $\alpha$.

Comment: Yes, this is correct, and your argument is the standard proof.

Comment: Thank you so much @AndrésE.Caicedo! You make me more confident in this chapter.